# How to get classlibrary.dll.config files in console application to add reference for the class library files?

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, console-application, class-library

First created class library project and added app.config files in this project. Then i was builded the project and open in the bin/debug folder it contains classlibrary.dll,classlibrary.dll.config and classlibrary.pdb files created.
Second created one console application and add reference the classlibrary.dll file. Then i was build the project  and open in the bin/debug folder it contains classlibrary.dll, classlibrary.pdb, ConsoleApplication1.exe, ConsoleApplication1.exe.config, ConsoleApplication1.pdb files are created. But classlibrary.dll.config file was not created. How can i get the classlibrary.dll.config file? Please help me.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, only the app.config file for the *executable* is used... it's a bit of a problem in terms of the whole app.config story, IMO...

Answer (score 0):

There is not .config file for libraries, only for executables, so, you should move all the config settings to ConsoleApplication1.exe.config

Comment: Is it possible to get classlibrary.dll.config file automatically builded in console application bin folder.?

Comment: Yes, it can be done easily in post build event, but this is not the way of handling this. As I said, you must move all the config to the executable configuration file.

Comment: Without post build event & manually copy, not possible to get classlibrary.dll.config file automatically in console application bin folder?

Comment: @user3671485 Yes, you can select file in Solution Explorer, select app.config, go to Properties windows and set property "Copy to output directory" to "Always" or "If newer". Beware, it will be named App.config, not MyDll.config. Just let me say this once more: in .net standard applications there is not such a thing as a library with a config file, config files are associated to executables.

Comment: Using MS build to get classlibrary.dll.config file automatically builded in console application bin folder.? If possible means kindly tell the steps.

Comment: Is it possible to get classlibrary.dll.config file automatically when build in console application bin/Debug folder using MSBUILD?